# How will DAL change Rollup message processing?

Tags: smart-rollup, rollup, scoru

How will DAL change Rollup message processing? Will current kernels still work with inbox/outbox etc.?

Question from Asbjorn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the kernel would like to support the Data Availability Layer, it would likely need to be upgraded to support it, if it does not already.

That being said, a pre-existing/deployed kernel *would not* need any changes to continue working as before, with the Inbox/Outbox.

Any data from the DAL would be ultimately imported through the *reveal data channel* mechanism.

Answer (score 2):

To be able to use the DAL, a kernel must be aware of the DAL.

For kernel written before the DAL is activated, likely an upgrade of the kernel will be needed.

Then, as @Emma Turner said, we will use a similar mechanism to the one used for the DAC via this reveal mechanism. One thing to note is that, while the roll-up kernel **must** read data from the inbox, it is up to the kernel to decide which data from the DAL the kernel wants to read.